# CocoaPodsでライブラリのバージョンをSwiftのバージョンに合わせる方法

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

お世話になります。
CocoaPodsでインストールするライブラリのバージョンをSwiftのバージョンに合わせる方法はありませんか。

環境
Xcode 9.0
CocoaPods 1.3.1

設定
プロジェクト本体のSwiftLanguageVersion 3.2
PodsのSwiftLanguageVersion 3.2

この状態でpod updateをするとSwift4の書き方のバージョンがインストールされます。
これをSwift3.2や3.0に解決してくれるような方法は無いでしょうか。

Podfileの内容

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

target '本体のターゲット名' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Eureka'
  pod 'CTFeedback'
  pod 'AcknowList'
  pod 'FAQView'
  pod 'CRToast'

  target 'テストのターゲット名' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

もっと良い方法があるかもしれませんが、参考になれば。

Swift 3.2 で書かれていた時点でのバージョンを指定すれば、質問者様の環境でもビルドできると思います。

今回のケースだと、Eureka, AcknowList の最新バージョンが Swift 4 で書かれているため、ちょっと古めのバージョンに戻してあげます。

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

target '本体のターゲット名' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Eureka', :git => 'https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka', :branch => 'feature/Xcode9-Swift3_2'
  pod 'CTFeedback'
  pod 'AcknowList', :git => 'https://github.com/vtourraine/AcknowList', :commit => '9e8b881404c65b8e2e0cd0701ea2a0a7b386d263'
  pod 'FAQView'
  pod 'CRToast'

  target 'テストのターゲット名' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end
```

これでビルドできないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。ビルド出来ました。やはりブランチ名やコミットを指定する（手動で調べる）方法しか無いですかね・・・・・・

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6791 ここでも議論されているみたいですねー

Comment: やり方はそれしかないと思いますが、固定するのは可能ならブランチやコミットではなくバージョンを指定するほうがいいですね。ブランチは消えることもありますし。問題の`Eureka`や`AcknowList`はCHANGELOGがきちんと書かれているので、Swift 4に変わったところを調べるのも容易だと思います。

Comment: swift_versionはビルドする時にどのバージョンのSwiftとして扱うかということなんですね。てっきり自動でバージョンにあわせてライブラリのバージョンを解決してくれる仕組みがあるのかと思っていました。CHANGELOGを見て指定するようにしてみます。お二人ともありがとうございました！